# Animating svg fill from bottom to top

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have a simple layout:

- split screen, one section is white, the other is black.
- centered logo, half black and half white
- when you hover the black section, it gets filled from bottom to top with white

Now, **what I try to do**:

- Fill the logo from bottom to top with black when I hover the section on the right.
- Fill the logo from top to bottom with white when I hover the section on the left

I tried many things... but I always failed.

I think the easiest solution would be to have a rectangle with a linear gradient as a background-image, add a mask and then move the background-position.

Here is a snippet:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".split-half").hover(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    $(".split-half").each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        elem.addClass('active');
      }, 400);      
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body *, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.split-half {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5%;
}
.split-half:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
}
.split-half:nth-child(1):after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  transition: height .3s;
}
.split-half:nth-child(1).active:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.split-half:nth-child(2) {
  background: #000;
  right: 0;
}
.split-half:nth-child(2):after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transition: height .3s;
}
.split-half:nth-child(2).active:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.split-half:nth-child(2).active:hover + #logo #rect {
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-39.8%, -50%);
  max-width: 420px;
  min-width: 120px;
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}
#logo #rect {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, white 50%, black 50%, black 100%);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s;
  mask: url(#mhSvg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
            <div class="split-half"></div>
            <div class="split-half">
            </div>
            <div id="logo">
                <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 187 174" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">   
                    <defs>
                        <g id="hSvg">
                            <path d="M74.624,173.782l111.609,-55.886l-24.82,-12.41l-24.82,12.41l-24.82,-12.41l24.82,-12.41l-24.82,-12.41l-111.773,55.804l24.984,12.492l61.969,-31.066l24.82,12.41l-61.969,31.066" style="fill:#fff;"/>
                        </g>
                        <mask id="mhSvg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                            <g id="hSvg">
                                <path d="M74.624,173.782l111.609,-55.886l-24.82,-12.41l-24.82,12.41l-24.82,-12.41l24.82,-12.41l-24.82,-12.41l-111.773,55.804l24.984,12.492l61.969,-31.066l24.82,12.41l-61.969,31.066" style="fill:#fff;"/>
                            </g>       
                        </mask>                 
                        <g id="aSvg">
                            <path d="M0.082,0l74.542,37.271l0,136.511l-24.82,-12.41l0,-62.05l-24.902,-12.451l0,62.05l-24.82,-12.41l0,-136.511Zm24.902,62.091l0,-24.82l24.82,12.41l0,24.821l-24.82,-12.411Z"/>
                        </g>    
                    </defs>       
                    <g>
                        <use xlink:href="#hSvg" x="0" y="0" />
                        <use xlink:href="#aSvg" x="0" y="0" />
                    </g>                  
                </svg>
                <div id="rect">
                </div>      
            </div>
        </section>
```

For now, as you can see, I fail to position the mask.

Do you know how I can position the mask ?

Or **do you think of a better method** to achieve the effect ?

Thank you in advance !

**Edit:**

Well, I found a solution with masks... but it won't be a good solution as it's not cross browsers.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".split-half").hover(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    $(".split-half").each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        elem.addClass('active');
      }, 400);      
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* line 3, ../sass/style.scss */
body *, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
.split-half {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5%;
}
.split-half:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
}
.split-half:nth-child(1):after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  transition: height .3s;
}
.split-half:nth-child(1).active:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.split-half:nth-child(1).active:hover ~ #logo #A {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
.split-half:nth-child(2) {
  background: #000;
  right: 0;
}
.split-half:nth-child(2):after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transition: height .3s;
}
.split-half:nth-child(2).active:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
/* line 58, ../sass/style.scss */
.split-half:nth-child(2).active:hover + #logo #H {
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-38.5%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}
#logo #H {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, white 50%, black 50%, black 100%);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s;
  mask: url(#mhSvg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#logo #A {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, white 50%, black 50%, black 100%);
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s;
  mask: url(#maSvg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
            <div class="split-half"></div>
            <div class="split-half">
            </div>
            <div id="logo">
                <svg width="194" height="181" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">   
                    <defs>
                        <g id="hSvg">
                            <path d="M74.624,173.782l111.609,-55.886l-24.82,-12.41l-24.82,12.41l-24.82,-12.41l24.82,-12.41l-24.82,-12.41l-111.773,55.804l24.984,12.492l61.969,-31.066l24.82,12.41l-61.969,31.066" style="fill:#fff;"/>
                        </g>
                        <mask id="mhSvg" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="114">
                            <g id="hSvg">
                                <path d="M74.624,173.782l111.609,-55.886l-24.82,-12.41l-24.82,12.41l-24.82,-12.41l24.82,-12.41l-24.82,-12.41l-111.773,55.804l24.984,12.492l61.969,-31.066l24.82,12.41l-61.969,31.066" style="fill:#fff;"/>
                            </g>       
                        </mask>
                        <mask id="maSvg" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="114">                                      
                            <g id="aSvg">
                                <path d="M0.082,0l74.542,37.271l0,136.511l-24.82,-12.41l0,-62.05l-24.902,-12.451l0,62.05l-24.82,-12.41l0,-136.511Zm24.902,62.091l0,-24.82l24.82,12.41l0,24.821l-24.82,-12.411Z" style="fill:#fff"/>
                            </g>
                        </mask>    
                    </defs>       
                    <g>              
                </svg>
                <div id="H">
                </div>      
                <div id="A">
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </section>
```

I may have to dig at the suggestion made by @RobertLongson that is to say animate the stops of a linear-gradient.

**Edit 2:**

I tried animating the linear-gradient position, thanks to **kute.js**.
It works in firefox, chrome, but not in IE/Edge or on the website, they do have an [exemple working on IE/Edge](http://thednp.github.io/kute.js/attr.html).

Here is my pen, I'm still wondering why it doesn't work.
https://codepen.io/AmauryH/pen/brBgKo

Comment: fill the shape with a linear gradient and animate the stops.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I tried, but I failed to animate it on hover.

Comment: @Lars Thank you for the edit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally decided to start from a blank page and went for a different approach.

- A container with a linear-gradient background (half white/half black) and the logo as a svg background-image
- Two more containers inside with height 0. One with a black background, the other with a white background
- In each a fullscreen span with the logo as a background image. (one logo full black, the other full white)

Then, I just have to animate the height of the containers from 0 to 100% to get the transition I wanted.

To get the white background to fill the screen from bottom to top, I had to use a simple trick... I've rotated the container with the background from a 180deg angle, and I've rotated it's children with the same angle.

Here is a snippet:

```js
var vHeight = $(window).height();
var vWidth = $(window).width();
var screen1 = $('#screen1');

var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
  if ( currentMousePos.y <= vHeight ){
    if ( currentMousePos.x >= ((vWidth / 2) + (vWidth / 10)) ) {
      $('.svgb-wrapper').css('height', '0');   
      $('.svgw-wrapper').css('height', '100%');
    }
    else if ( currentMousePos.x <= ((vWidth / 2) - (vWidth / 10)) ) {
      $('.svgb-wrapper').css('height', '100%'); 
      $('.svgw-wrapper').css('height', '0'); 
    }
    else {
      $('.svgb-wrapper').css('height', '0'); 
      $('.svgw-wrapper').css('height', '0');     
    }
  };
});
```

```css
* {
margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
}
body *, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#screen1 {
  height: 100%;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTg3IDE3NCIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW\a 5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbC1ydWxlOmV2ZW5vZGQ7Y2xpcC1ydWxlOmV2ZW5vZGQ7c3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVqb2lu\aOnJvdW5kO3N0cm9rZS1taXRlcmxpbWl0OjEuNDE0MjE7Ij48cmVjdCBpZD0iUGxhbi1kZS10cmF2YWlsMSIgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjE4Ni4zNjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTczLjc4MiIgc3R5bG\aU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTsiLz48Y2xpcFBhdGggaWQ9Il9jbGlwMSI+PHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjE4Ni4zNjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTczLjc4MiIvPjwvY2xpcFBhdGg+PGcgY2xpcC1wYXRo\aPSJ1cmwoI19jbGlwMSkiPjxwYXRoIGlkPSJoU3ZnIiBkPSJNNzQuNjI0LDE3My43ODJsMTExLjYwOSwtNTUuODg2bC0yNC44MiwtMTIuNDFsLTI0LjgyLDEyLjQxbC0yNC44MiwtMTIuNDFsMjQuOD\aIsLTEyLjQxbC0yNC44MiwtMTIuNDFsLTExMS43NzMsNTUuODA0bDI0Ljk4NCwxMi40OTJsNjEuOTY5LC0zMS4wNjZsMjQuODIsMTIuNDFsLTYxLjk2OSwzMS4wNjYiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiNmZmY7\aIi8+PHBhdGggaWQ9ImFTdmciIGQ9Ik0wLjA4MiwwbDc0LjU0MiwzNy4yNzFsMCwxMzYuNTExbC0yNC44MiwtMTIuNDFsMCwtNjIuMDVsLTI0LjkwMiwtMTIuNDUxbDAsNjIuMDVsLTI0LjgyLC0xMi\a 40MWwwLC0xMzYuNTExbDAsMFptMjQuOTAyLDYyLjA5MWwwLC0yNC44MmwyNC44MiwxMi40MWwwLDI0LjgyMWwtMjQuODIsLTEyLjQxMWwwLDBaIi8+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==") no-repeat left 55% center, linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 50%, #000000 50%, #000000 100%);
  background-size: 33%, cover;
}
#screen1 .svgw-wrapper {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  background: #000;
}
#screen1 .svgw-wrapper .svgw {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+PCF\a ET0NUWVBFIHN2ZyBQVUJMSUMgIi0vL1czQy8vRFREIFNWRyAxLjEvL0VOIiAiaHR0cDovL3d3dy\a 53My5vcmcvR3JhcGhpY3MvU1ZHLzEuMS9EVEQvc3ZnMTEuZHRkIj48c3ZnIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlI\aiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxODcgMTc0IiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5z\aPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzM\aub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsLXJ1bGU6ZX\aZlbm9kZDtjbGlwLXJ1bGU6ZXZlbm9kZDtzdHJva2UtbGluZWpvaW46cm91bmQ7c3Ryb2tlLW1pd\aGVybGltaXQ6MS40MTQyMTsiPjxyZWN0IGlkPSJQbGFuLWRlLXRyYXZhaWwxIiB4PSIwIiB5PSIw\aIiB3aWR0aD0iMTg2LjM2OCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNzMuNzgyIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lOyIvPjx\ajbGlwUGF0aCBpZD0iX2NsaXAxIj48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTg2LjM2OCIgaG\aVpZ2h0PSIxNzMuNzgyIi8+PC9jbGlwUGF0aD48ZyBjbGlwLXBhdGg9InVybCgjX2NsaXAxKSI+P\aHBhdGggaWQ9ImhTdmciIGQ9Ik03NC42MjQsMTczLjc4MmwxMTEuNjA5LC01NS44ODZsLTI0Ljgy\aLC0xMi40MWwtMjQuODIsMTIuNDFsLTI0LjgyLC0xMi40MWwyNC44MiwtMTIuNDFsLTI0LjgyLC0\axMi40MWwtMTExLjc3Myw1NS44MDRsMjQuOTg0LDEyLjQ5Mmw2MS45NjksLTMxLjA2NmwyNC44Mi\awxMi40MWwtNjEuOTY5LDMxLjA2NiIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6I2ZmZjsiLz48cGF0aCBpZD0iYVN2Z\ayIgZD0iTTAuMDgyLDBsNzQuNTQyLDM3LjI3MWwwLDEzNi41MTFsLTI0LjgyLC0xMi40MWwwLC02\aMi4wNWwtMjQuOTAyLC0xMi40NTFsMCw2Mi4wNWwtMjQuODIsLTEyLjQxbDAsLTEzNi41MTFsMCw\awWm0yNC45MDIsNjIuMDkxbDAsLTI0LjgybDI0LjgyLDEyLjQxbDAsMjQuODIxbC0yNC44MiwtMT\aIuNDExbDAsMFoiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiNmZmY7Ii8+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==") no-repeat left 55% center;
  background-size: 33%;
}
#screen1 .svgb-wrapper {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
#screen1 .svgb-wrapper .svgb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTg3IDE3NCIgdmV\ayc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW\a 5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIiBzd\aHlsZT0iZmlsbC1ydWxlOmV2ZW5vZGQ7Y2xpcC1ydWxlOmV2ZW5vZGQ7c3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVqb2lu\aOnJvdW5kO3N0cm9rZS1taXRlcmxpbWl0OjEuNDE0MjE7Ij48cmVjdCBpZD0iUGxhbi1kZS10cmF\a 2YWlsMSIgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjE4Ni4zNjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTczLjc4MiIgc3R5bG\aU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTsiLz48Y2xpcFBhdGggaWQ9Il9jbGlwMSI+PHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd\a 2lkdGg9IjE4Ni4zNjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTczLjc4MiIvPjwvY2xpcFBhdGg+PGcgY2xpcC1wYXRo\aPSJ1cmwoI19jbGlwMSkiPjxwYXRoIGlkPSJoU3ZnIiBkPSJNNzQuNjI0LDE3My43ODJsMTExLjY\awOSwtNTUuODg2bC0yNC44MiwtMTIuNDFsLTI0LjgyLDEyLjQxbC0yNC44MiwtMTIuNDFsMjQuOD\aIsLTEyLjQxbC0yNC44MiwtMTIuNDFsLTExMS43NzMsNTUuODA0bDI0Ljk4NCwxMi40OTJsNjEuO\aTY5LC0zMS4wNjZsMjQuODIsMTIuNDFsLTYxLjk2OSwzMS4wNjYiLz48cGF0aCBpZD0iYVN2ZyIg\aZD0iTTAuMDgyLDBsNzQuNTQyLDM3LjI3MWwwLDEzNi41MTFsLTI0LjgyLC0xMi40MWwwLC02Mi4\awNWwtMjQuOTAyLC0xMi40NTFsMCw2Mi4wNWwtMjQuODIsLTEyLjQxbDAsLTEzNi41MTFsMCwwWm\a 0yNC45MDIsNjIuMDkxbDAsLTI0LjgybDI0LjgyLDEyLjQxbDAsMjQuODIxbC0yNC44MiwtMTIuN\a DExbDAsMFoiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+") no-repeat left 55% center;
  background-size: 33%;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
#screen2 {
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.2.0/zepto.min.js"></script>
        <section id="screen1">
            <div class="svgw-wrapper">
                <span class="svgw"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="svgb-wrapper">
                <span class="svgb"></span>                
            </div>
        </section>
```

It's a cross browser solution. 
The only problem is the `background-position` and the `background-size` that are not working as expected in IE, but I'll probably live with that !

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.  I'm using an animated CSS `linear-gradient` for the `split-half` `<div>` elements.  And using `mix-blend-mode: difference` to ensure the logo contrasts with the animated background.

This should work on all browsers except IE/Edge.

```css
body *, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.split-half {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5%;
}

.split-half:nth-child(1) {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff 50%,#000000 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  left: 0;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}
.split-half:nth-child(1):hover {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.split-half:nth-child(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff 50%,#000000 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  right: 0;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}
.split-half:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-39.8%, -50%);
  max-width: 420px;
  min-width: 120px;
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="split-half"></div>
  <div class="split-half"></div>

  <div id="logo">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 187 174" style="fill-rule:evenodd;">   
      <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="0" y1="100%" x2="0" y2="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="white"/>
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>

      <g>
        <path id="hSvg" d="M74.624,173.782l111.609,-55.886l-24.82,-12.41l-24.82,12.41l-24.82,-12.41l24.82,-12.41l-24.82,-12.41l-111.773,55.804l24.984,12.492l61.969,-31.066l24.82,12.41l-61.969,31.066" style="fill:#fff;"/>
        <path id="aSvg" d="M0.082,0l74.542,37.271l0,136.511l-24.82,-12.41l0,-62.05l-24.902,-12.451l0,62.05l-24.82,-12.41l0,-136.511Zm24.902,62.091l0,-24.82l24.82,12.41l0,24.821l-24.82,-12.411Z" style="fill:#fff;"/>
      </g>    
    </svg>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for the answer, but as you said, there is a big disadvantage.. it's not crossbrowser.
You can also see that there's no hole in the shape of the "A" anymore, is it because of the `mix-blend` ?

Comment: The missing hole was because I accidentally removed the `fill-rule: evenodd;`. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Hello, I must admit that it runs really smoothly, but I'd like a IE10 & Edge compatible solution.

Comment: You should be able to do it using JS to animate a linearGradient on each of your SVG path elements.  There are many examples of how to do that on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hello Paul, thank you for your answer. I did try to animate the coordinates of the linear gradient, but I couldn't get it to work.
I've decided to start again from a blank page and I came up with another solution.